# How to download QR code image of Google Chart API in php?

Tags: php, api, qr-code

As we all know google provide as Free API named:[developer.google.com](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes)

And I am looking a way to download the QR CODE image in any format(jpg, png).
I am creating dynamic Url which is pass to **chl** attribute of google API.

**example:**

```
 <?php
  $long_url = $row['urlinput']; //dynamic url is comming from database
   echo '<div class="crop img-thumbnail img-responsive">
              <img  class=" crop" src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl='.$long_url.'&choe=UTF-8" title="'.$long_url.'" />
         </div>';

  ?>
```

**example output:**

[image: here]

**What I am trying to achieve is:** download this QR CODE and save it into my computer.

I use: `<a href="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl='.$long_url.'" download>download</a>` But it seems it not working.

If there is any guidance or direction is provide then its my great honour.

Comment: "not working" how, exactly? What happens when you make that request? What response do you get from the server?

Comment: I get redirected to the URL  when I hit download link.

Comment: Ok well that's what your browser will do if you link it to an image file. Browsers are set by default to display images files inline, instead of download it. You could see that with any image URL. You can just right-click on it to download it, of course. That's not google's fault.

Comment: so, what can I do to force it to download?

Comment: Nothing, unless you can change the file types that your browser will recognise. But then you'll likely have problems displaying images in other webpages. The only other option is if the google API documentation describes any specific URL parameter you can send, which will cause it to emit headers along with the image response, that your browser will follow as an instruction to download the file instead of displaying it.

Comment: :( thanks for your response ADyson.

Comment: of course instead of running this code on your server and then creating a hyperlink for download via a browser, you could just run some code directly on your own computer to access these URLs and download the data directly onto your disk.

Comment: direct link of any image is works perfect but not with google API

Comment: Right. But did you see my last comment? You can just bypass the browser problem entirely and run some code on your own PC, if that's where you want to put the data.

Comment: yes sir, but that's not  I am looking for. its only works for my browser, not for my users.

Comment: I see. You didn't entirely make the situation clear. Anyway, if you can give me a link to an image URL which will download automatically as you mentioned, and a link to a google image URL which doesn't, maybe I can compare the responses and see if there is a reason for the difference.

Comment: <img  class=" crop" src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54737647/how-to-download-qr-code-image-of-google-chart-api-in-php&choe=UTF-8"  />  Use this image

Comment: `https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54737647/how-to-download-qr-code-image-of-google-chart-api-in-php&choe=UTF-8` just opens in my browser. Ok. What about one you're saying downloads automatically?

Comment: I want the QR Code image to be download on my browser

Comment: Ok. but before you said "direct link of any image is works perfect but not with google API". So what is this direct link you're referring to? Like I said, I'd like to compare it to the google one. So then I can tell you if there's some difference you can make use of.

Comment: this is what direct link means: <a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
  <img src="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
</a>

Comment: example: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download

Comment: Ah ok so it's nothing to do with the actual image or the response headers etc, it's all about the `download` tag in the `<a` element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes says of the "download" attribute: _"This attribute only works for **same-origin** URLs."_ (my bold). Clearly in the w3schools example the image is on the same domain as the web page. Whereas in your case it's not - the URL is from google, not from the domain of your page. So in your situation the `download` attribute has no effect, and the browser goes back to its normal behaviour.

Comment: Take that `download` attribute away from the w3schools example and it displays the image in the browser just like normal. The fact it's a direct link to an image file (rather than a URL which generates an image) is irrelevant.

Comment: hmm. I Guess that is only I can do at the moment.

Comment: Thankyou so much ADyson for help meout.

Comment: The only workaround I can think of is to provide your user with a link to a PHP script on your own webserver instead of the google URL. You'd have to pass it some unique identifier of the QR code, like you do when you make the link to google. Passing the same parameters would make a lot of sense. That script will then make a secondary HTTP request to the google API (e.g. using `cURL`), fetch the data, and then echo that data back to the browser, while also setting appropriate image-related response headers.

Comment: That way, the image URL will appear to the browser as being on the same origin as the page, and so a `download` attribute will work. It's just a little bit less efficient because your webserver has to process an extra request from your user and also make an extra request to google, rather than the user fetching the data directly from google into their browser. But it does work round your issue.

Comment: Hmmm I see, thanks for the solution.